# How To Add Days Using Moment with format of mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a bit of code that's dynamic. The date format is set through a system setting, the variable is called `vm.dateTimeFormat`. My goal is to add 7 days to my current end date.

I've come across code from other post and this is the bit of code I created.

```
vm.dateTimeFormatPlaceholder = 'mm/dd/yyyy'
```

eDate is originally `08/09/2019`

```
if (eDate != sDate)
{
    var endDate = moment(eDate);
    console.log(endDate.add(7, 'days'));
    eDate = endDate.format(vm.dateTimeFormatPlaceholder);
}
```

When that bit of code is ran, `eDate` ends up with a value of `00/Th/yyyy`

Comment: month is MM and day is DD and year is YYYY.. all upcase

Comment: Look at [the documentation for `format` and you'll see all of the format strings](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your datetime format: it should be `DD/MM/YYYY`, all upcase.

```js
dateTimeFormatPlaceholder = 'MM/DD/YYYY'
const eDay = moment('20190908');

const endDate = moment(eDay);
console.log(endDate.add(7, 'days').format());
const eDate = endDate.format(dateTimeFormatPlaceholder);

console.log(eDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

In docs:

> **Year, month, and day tokens**
>
> *Tokens are case-sensitive.*
>
> `M MM`    Ex:`1..12`  Month number
>
> `D DD`    Ex:`1..31`  Day of month
>
> `YYYY`    Ex:`2014`   4 or 2 digit year

Documentation [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this `endDate.add(7, 'days').format("MM/DD/YYYY")`. The format() is case-sensitive

In your case, `vm.dateTimeFormatPlaceholder = 'MM/DD/YYYY'`